# Understanding how to implement Adaptive learning rate and momentum to a NN

Tags: vb.net, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

I have been trying recently to create an adaptive learning rate and momentum with no success. I have successfully create a working NN, however the trouble I am finding is choosing the right learning rate.

This is why I decided to use an adaptive learning rate, but, no matter the amount of research I have done on the topic, I simply do not understand the algorithms, probably due to me being new to neural networks.

I was wondering if anyone with the knowledge to simplify these algorithms for momentum and an adaptive learning rate would be able to post an explanation that beginners can understand. I am using VB.net console application to program it if that gives you a sense of how much of a beginner I am.

Thank you very much for your time. If I have asked a bad question or one that doesn't make sense, please let me know and I will try to fix the question :)

Thank you all.

PETER JAMIESON

Comment: The question isn't completely clear, is it the method you don't understand or the code?  If the code you should provide some demonstrated coding effort to help us understand where you problem is.

Comment: I think it is the method as I can implement the code that i have seen on websites, however they dont seem to work for me and the one mentioned in the Viceriel's answer converges to 0 so I believe i am either misinterpreting the code providied or understanding the method incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

So I heard about two algorithms for adaptive learning rate.

- Delta bar delta rule
- fuzzy logic

I have experience only with fuzzy logic. So, you pass your samples and compute error for dataset and also derror(actual error - error in previous epoch). And based on this you build an intuitive rules like

**IF is error BIG AND derror SMALL THEN change of learning rate is BIG**

etc. For perform such thing you must know approximately bounds of error. For example you perform classification task and you have only two classes. So the worst errors are 5 and -5(5 for all samples are 1 but network classifies them as 0, -5 vice versa). This range defines you universum(x axis). For derror you perform similar computation. So you have ranges and now you can build fuzzy sets. For building sets I can't recommend approach. Only try error mixed with simple logic(big error need big improvement).

[Here is some notes about fuzzy logic and learning rate and also Matlab implementation](http://neuron.tuke.sk/koscelansky/HviZadanie1.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I think I may have came across something similar before where it basically said if the previous error is larger, multiply the learning rate by a scale factor of 1.05,else multiply it by 0.7, I have tried this in my code and the learning rate seems to converge to 0, is this the same thing that you meant, and is the error that you are talking bout the error off the output/s